# Run a download directly from Firefox 4, without saving it somewhere first

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Ever since upgrading to Firefox 4, I lost one of my favourite addons, RunDownload. Now instead of just running a file directly, I have to pick a save directory first, then run it, and then delete it afterwards.

Is there any way to get Firefox 4 to offer a Run button, which would download the EXE to a temporary location and run it?

(no need to explain why you think it's a bad idea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox doesn't allow you to "Run" an installer from the download window (security is the reason), but there is an extension which will enable the option.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/opendownload-271182/

[image]

EDIT: The original extension is no longer available.

Here is an alternative -  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/opendownload-10902/